# Is it possible to integrate a Chrome Extension with Google Classroom?

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, google-classroom

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension that can show you how many assignments you currently have for Google Classroom.  Does anyone know how to get started or any tutorials on how to do something like this?

Comment: The Chrome tutorial is pretty nice. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to integrate.
you can refer https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/ for the rest Api's of Google Classroom (if needed) or can inject your own content_script into the Google Classroom page to fetch the required info. Creating an extension is very easy. you can follow the docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions